# loading resources in tiles & spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, tiles

I am using spring mvc 3 and tiles 2 with wildcard definitions. I want to load additional css and javascript files inside some of my tiles. Is there way to do this? Preferably in tile jsp file, not in tiles-definitions.xml.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a good question because one of the main benefits of tiles is the central view it provides with regards to composition. It would be really nice if this centralization could also include CSS & JS files as well.

It happens that this *is* possible, here is an example. This example uses tiles3 however it should be pretty simple to adapt to tiles-2 (tiles three lets you use multiple types of expressions) you can side step this.

Also note that I use Struts2 as my action framework, this is not an issue but as I'm going to use a working example you'll know the "OGNL:" prefixed expression means that the EL Struts2 uses will be used. You should also know that if you upgrade to Tiles-3 you can also use Spring EL by prefixing your expressions with "MVEL:".

**tiles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN" "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="default" template="/WEB-INF/template/template.jsp">
        <put-list-attribute name="cssList" cascade="true">
            <add-attribute value="/style/cssreset-min.css" />
            <add-attribute value="/style/cssfonts-min.css" />
            <add-attribute value="/style/cssbase-min.css" />  
            <add-attribute value="/style/grids-min.css" />
            <add-attribute value="/script/jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom.css" />
            <add-attribute value="/style/style.css" />
        </put-list-attribute>    
        <put-list-attribute name="jsList" cascade="true">
            <add-attribute value="/script/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js" />
            <add-attribute value="/script/jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom.min.js" />
            <add-attribute value="/script/jquery.sort.js" />
            <add-attribute value="/script/custom/jquery-serialize.js" />
        </put-list-attribute>   
        <put-attribute name="title" value="defaults-name" cascade="true"  type="string"/>
        <put-attribute name="head" value="/WEB-INF/template/head.jsp"/>
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/template/header.jsp"/>
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/template/body.jsp"/>
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/template/footer.jsp"/>
    </definition>

    <definition name="REGEXP:\/recruiter#candidate-input\.(.*)"  extends="default">
        <put-list-attribute name="cssList" cascade="true" inherit="true">
            <add-attribute value="/style/recruiter/candidate-input.css" />
        </put-list-attribute>
        <put-list-attribute name="jsList" cascade="true" inherit="true">
            <add-attribute value="/script/widgets/resume/resume.js" />
        </put-list-attribute>
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/content/recruiter/candidate-input.jsp"/>
    </definition>

    <definition name="REGEXP:(.*)#(.*)"  extends="default">
        <put-attribute name="title" cascade="true" expression="OGNL:@com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext@getContext().name"/>
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/content{1}/{2}"/>
    </definition>   
</tiles-definitions>
```

**/WEB-INF/template/template.jsp**

```
<%@taglib prefix="tiles" uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" %>
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="head"/>
    <body>
        <%--  website header --%>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="content">
                <tiles:insertAttribute name="header"/>
                <tiles:insertAttribute name="body"/>
                <div class ="outer content">
                    <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the important part getting the lists of CSS files and JS files into the head tile:

**/WEB-INF/template/head.jsp**

```
<%@taglib prefix="tiles" uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles"%>
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<tiles:importAttribute name="cssList"/><tiles:importAttribute name="jsList"/>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <s:iterator value="#attr.cssList" var="cssValue">
        <link href="<s:url value="%{cssValue}"/>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </s:iterator>
    <s:iterator value="#attr.jsList" var="jsValue">
        <script src="<s:url value="%{jsValue}"/>"></script>
    </s:iterator>
    <title><tiles:insertAttribute name="title" defaultValue="no title"/></title>
</head>
```

I think you can figure out the rest. Sorry about the `<s:iterator>` tags in the last block, I'm not sure of the Spring equivalent nor would I be inclined to test it. But should you translate this to Spring, it would be great for you to self answer here. I'd happily up vote it.

Comment: thanks for this detailed answer. So the way to do this is removing the special page from the wildcard and putting it in a definition of its own. I wish there was a tiles tag that I can use in body that will insert resources to the head.

Comment: That can't exist for efficiency reasons. You'll notice on large page loads (with a slow connection) that data is streaming to the page. This prevents the data from being buffered on the server side saving resources. If you want the type of interaction you explained there are two options: 1) Use sitemesh (You pay for this feature in that the content is buffered) 2) Something I'm thinking about working on: build a layer on top of tiles, where you store definition data in a DB. When a definition is inserted into the database you can define all the dependencies when you pull the tiles defs...

Comment: Say the body tile requires 3 css files, 2 js files, then when the tile definition is retrieved from the DB, we can get a list of all the required resources. It is true that tiles renders top down but if we can get all the required ingredients before the rendering starts! We can get decorator (SiteMesh) benefits with the efficiency composition (tiles).

Comment: Thanks alot. This very helpful for strut2 and tiles.

Answer (score 1):

In dispatcher-servlet.xml provide mvc static resource mapping as following :

```
<!-- static resource mapping for style sheets, etc. -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/styles/**"  location="/WEB-INF/skins/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/scripts/**" location="/WEB-INF/scripts/" />
```

And on your tiles-layout.jsp file you can access them all by writing

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${context}/scripts/jquery-1.7.js></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${context}/styles/css/superfish.css">
```

See: [mvc:resources](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-static-resources)

Answer (score 1):

That is how I did with Spring, the rest is just like Quaternion posted.

**/WEB-INF/template/head.jsp**

```
<tiles:importAttribute name="cssList"/>
<tiles:importAttribute name="jsList"/>
<head>
    <c:forEach var="cssValue" items="${cssList}">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="${cssValue}"/>" />
    </c:forEach>

    <c:forEach var="jsValue" items="${jsList}">
        <script src="<c:url value="${jsValue}"/>"></script>
    </c:forEach>
</head>
```

And don't forget to point on each page the right definition from **tiles.xml**

```
<tiles:insertDefinition name="definitionName">
    <tiles:putAttribute name="body">
        //content
    </tiles:putAttribute>
</tiles:insertDefinition>
```